# When using createrawtransaction, are the outputs ordered as they are presented within the request?

Tags: json-rpc

Let say, when I set second parameter of `craterawtransaction` call as below

```
[{"demoaddress1": 0.42}, {"demoaddress2": 1.00}]
```

Is it possible to occur that returned transaction's output is not ordered as same? like below

```
[{"demoaddress2": 1.00}, {"demoaddress1": 0.42}]
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer on mailing list.

https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/bitcoin-dev/2018-October/016441.html

> The `createrawtransaction` RPC will now accept an array or dictionary (kept for compatibility) for the `outputs` parameter. This means the order of transaction outputs can be specified by the client.

According to the description, it should be the same order.